# Grabbing form data from a post request via node?

Tags: node.js

I am trying to see if I can grab values from form inputs but currently, I grab nothing. Do I need to change my form information so that the inputs become tied to the form? Or am I completely off the mark in my post request code? I figured that when I click the submit button, that would trigger the post request, and it does because I do get sent to the "Great" response. But the body object is always empty in the console.

```
var request = require('request');
var cheerio = require('cheerio');
var express = require('express');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var app = express();

app.get('/', function(req, res) {
  res.send(`
  <html>
    <body>
      <form action="http://localhost:3000/" method="post">
        <input type="text" name="fname" value="great"><br>
        <input type="text" name='lname' value="stuff"></br>
        <input type="submit" value="Submit">
      </form>
    </body>
  </html>
    `);
});
app.use(bodyParser.json())
app.post('/', function(req, res) {
  console.log(req.body);
  res.send('Great');
})

app.listen(3000);
```

Answer (score 0):

Like this:

```
app.post('/', function (req, res) {
    var body = '';

    req.on('data', function(chunk) {
        body += chunk;
    });

    req.on('end', function () {
        res.writeHead(200, 'OK', {'Content-Type': 'text/plain'});
        res.write(body);
        res.end ();
    });
});
```

So for instance, if you `POST` "Hello", this will write "Hello" in `res.write (body);`